# Hiding unwanted Symfony form fields from twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

When showing Symfony form in twig, how to hide field that is not in **form_widget**?

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.field1) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

And if I have **field2** in form type it will show by default in twig by no matter  that I had not insert in **form_widget**

```
class MessageFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('field1', TextType::class, array())

            ->add('field2', TextType::class, array())
    }
}
```

I am hiding those unwanted fieleds with css, bit I wonder if there some elegant solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html), you need to pass a key,value pair `'render_rest' : false` to the form_end tag.

> ```
> {# don't render unrendered fields #}
> {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
> ```

Comment: How could I miss that :)

Comment: but don't forget to render 'CSRF token' by adding `{{ form_row(form._token) }}` if token option is switched on, otherwise you'll get an error while submitting form

Comment: incomplete answer, see answer from sam_67 below for a full answer

Comment: @ChristopheBrun If you haven't already noticed, Stan has mentioned that in the comment above in the year of 2017.
Take the answers here as a step in the right direction but don't expect spoon feeding.

Answer (score 2):

```
{# don't render unrendered fields #}

{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

It is working, of course don't forget with this

```
{{ form_row(form._token) }}
```

Comment: this is the full answer - otherwise people using CSRF checks will run into validation errors